# C# How to sort 2 list as one?

Tags: c#, sorting

So, I have a struct:

```
struct Employee
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public string pw;
    public bool leader;
}
```

Then I read the datas from a text file.

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("employees.txt"))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    var temp = line.Split(':');
                    Employee employee = new Employee();
                    employee.id = Convert.ToInt32(temp[0]);
                    employee.name = temp[1];
                    employee.pw = temp[2];
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(temp[3]) == 0)
                    {
                        employee.leader = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        employee.leader = true;
                    }
                    employees.Add(employee);

List<int> projectsnumber = new List<int>();
```

If they work in a project, I add to projectnumber[employeeid]++; (I also read it from a textfile). If I create projectsnumber within the struct, I can't modify its value. The problem comes here. I have to display the names of employees depending on how much project they worked in. I can sort projectnumber in descending order, but then I can't display their name. If I look for the index of sorted numbers in projectsnumber, then if there are 2 same numbers, it will only display on of the employees, twice. So if I had a list with the numbers and names, I could write both. How could I do it?

Comment: In C#, one should default to `class` instead of `struct` ([Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply order employees by number of projects and select their names. It's easy to do with LINQ:

```
var names = employees.OrderByDescending(e => projectsnumber[e.id]).Select(e => e.name);
```

Query syntax:

```
var names = from e in employees
            orderby projectsnumber[e.id] descending
            select e.name;
```

If you need both name and projects count, then you can project employees to anonymous type:

```
var query = from e in employees
            let projectsCount = projectsnumber[e.id]
            orderby projectsCount descending
            select new {
               ProjectsCount = projectsCount,
               Name = e.name
            };
```

NOTE: As @crashmstr noted it's better to use classes instead of structures. And in C# we use Pascal Case for class/structure properties and methods names.